# Trying to simplify a Boolean expression

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

Simplify the following expression using Boolean Algebra:
$$ x = \bar{A} \bar{B} \bar{C} +  \bar{A}BC + ABC + A \bar{B} \bar{C} + A \bar{B} C $$
Answer:
\begin{align*}
x &= \bar{A} \bar{B} \bar{C} +  \bar{A}BC + ABC + A \bar{B} ( \bar{C} +  C ) \\
x &= \bar{A} \bar{B} \bar{C} +  \bar{A}BC + ABC + A \bar{B} \\
x &= \bar{A} \bar{B} \bar{C} +  \bar{A}BC + A( BC + \bar{B} ) \\
x &= \bar{A} \bar{B} \bar{C} +  \bar{A}BC + A( \bar{B} + C ) \\
x &= \bar{A} ( \bar{B} \bar{C} + BC ) + A( \bar{B} + C ) \\
\end{align*}
Now, I feel I am stuck. The book's answer is:
$$ x = BC + \bar{B}(\bar{C} + A) $$.

Based upon @StainlessSteelRat comments I tired this:
\begin{align*}
x &= \bar{A} \bar{B} \bar{C} + \bar{A} B C + ABC + A \bar{B}\bar{C} + A \bar{B}C \\
x &= \bar{A} \bar{B} \bar{C} + A \bar{B}\bar{C} + \bar{A} B C + ABC + A\bar{B}C + ABC \\
x &= \bar{B} \bar{C} ( \bar{A} + A) + BC(\bar{A} + A)  + AC(\bar{B} + B) \\
x &= \bar{B} \bar{C} + BC + AC \\
x &= \bar{B} \bar{C} + C(A + B )  \\
\end{align*}
However, I still get the wrong answer.

Comment: You can use the starting terms multiple times.  Term 3 & Term 5.  Your reduction on line 3 is incorrect.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I do not understand why this is wrong: $x = \bar{A} \bar{B} \bar{C} +  \bar{A}BC + A( BC + \bar{B} )$

Comment: Although, the 3rd line is correct mathematically, it is not the optimum.  You are correct and wrong.  Try reducing all 5 terms in the first step.  And there is two optimum solutions.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I do not see how to reduce all 5 terms in the first step since there is no common term in all 5.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Should I be applying one of DeMorgan's laws?

Comment: Try to reduce each term with other terms.  Repeat a term as required.  Does your answer look like the answer?  By doing two terms at a time, you have backed yourself into a corner.

Comment: No, DeMorgan's is not required.  Read all my comments!

Comment: Your answer is not wrong.  It is the second of the two possibilities.  Good job!  +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplify the following expression using Boolean Algebra:
$$ x = \bar{A} \bar{B} \bar{C} +  \bar{A}BC + ABC + A \bar{B} \bar{C} + A \bar{B} C $$
Answer:
\begin{align*}
x &= \bar{A} \bar{B} \bar{C} +  (\bar{A}+A)BC + A \bar{B} ( \bar{C} +  C ) \\
x &= \bar{A} \bar{B} \bar{C} +  BC + A \bar{B} \\
x &=  BC + \bar{B} ( A + \bar{A} \bar{C} ) \\
x &=  BC + \bar{B} ( (A + A \bar{C}) + \bar{A} \bar{C} ) \\
x &=  BC + \bar{B} ( A + (A + \bar{A}) \bar{C} ) \\
x &=  BC + \bar{B} ( A + \bar{C} )
\end{align*}

The trick is to introduce \$A \bar{C}\$ in the 4th line.

Comment: I do not understand how you went from $x =  BC + \bar{B} ( (A + A C) + \bar{A} \bar{C} )$ to $x =  BC + \bar{B} ( A + (A + \bar{A}) \bar{C} ) $$

Comment: I do not understand how you went from line 4 to line 5. Where you suppose to introduce $A\bar{C}$ instead of $AC$

Comment: Ok, I made a typeo - I forgot to add the bar on C.

Answer (score 3):

Actually your second solution as well as the textbook solution, both are right.

I put the expression for \$X\$ into K-map:
[image]

It gives me the reduced expression as:
$$X=\overline B\overline C+A\overline B  +BC$$
$$ie.,X=BC+\overline  B(A+\overline C) $$

But I can round the 1's in this manner as well:

[image]

It gives me the reduced expression as:
$$X=\overline B\overline C+AC  +BC$$
$$ie.,X=\overline B\overline C+C(A+B) $$

First solution is what your textbook derived.
Second solution is what you derived.
Both reduced expressions are right.